# Can I make my Windows 10 2-in-1 laptop wake from sleep by touching the touchscreen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, touchscreen, wake-up

How do I make my laptop wake up when I tap the touchscreen when it's sleeping/suspended?

I consulted some other posts on the Internet where people had a similar problem, but my laptop does not budge. I am unable to find a proper solution.

**Laptop:** HP envy x360 13z-ay000 2020 model.

- Windows 10 Home 64
- AMD Ryzen™ 7 processor
- AMD Radeon™ Graphics 8 GB
- Memory; 128 GB SSD storage
- 13.3" diagonal FHD touch display, IPS, BrightView, WLED-backlit, multitouch-enabled, Integrated privacy screen, 1000 nits (1920 x 1080)

Comment: It depends entirely on whether your laptop supports waking up from touchscreen events. It is not a Windows specific feature. You've given no details of your laptop so no one can say. You can [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: @Mokubai I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/wakeontouch

On AoAC systems (which includes all ARM systems), the system will automatically enter modern standby when the display goes off. When a system is in modern standby, it can only be woken by certain inputs. This is not an exhaustive list, but these inputs include pressing the power button, opening the lid on a laptop, or clicking the mouse. Touching the screen will not wake up the device from modern standby. If you want your device to wake up by touch, you have to configure the device not to enter modern standby. To disable modern standby, set the following registry key and reboot.

PowerShell
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power /v PlatformAoAcOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 0

Disabling modern standby can impact power consumption when the system is idle. You should measure your system's power consumption with modern standby enabled and disabled before making the decision to disable modern standby.

Modern standby is a software mechanism that attempts to quiet system activity as much as possible, thereby allowing hardware to enter a low-power state. In theory, a sufficiently quiet device with modern standby disabled can achieve the same low power consumption as a device in modern standby. It is important to minimize background activity including software timers and periodic tasks if modern standby is disabled.

Comment: When pasting text from web sites please format it as blockquote to make it clear that you have only copied it.